# Documenting Grape API

Tags: swagger, grape-api

I'm building a Grape API and most of my requests are based on JSON payloads and not parameters. I've heard that Swagger is not suitable in this regard. I would appreciate if someone could point out to me how the API can be documented effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I started using grape with swagger, but on the first time I was using the https://github.com/BrandyMint/grape-swagger-rails gem. But they're using a old version of swagger (code). So they need to change some pieces of code of the gem.

I started a project using swagger with bower, using the last version of the code. They improved all the code. Looks nice now.

I created a fork of the gem (https://github.com/pragmaticivan/grape-swagger-rails). So I made some changes of versions and configs. I'm using in a project now and it looks nice. The last version of grape-swagger (dependency of grape-swagger-rails) has soem new feature and you can choose a Markdown compiler for the code example of an endpoint.

I tested swagger-ui with bower on this project: https://github.com/larica/larica-api.
But on the future I'm gonna change to use the fork. It's working very nice now.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will have a look in to your gem and mark your answer if it works well. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok, if you need help let me know :D